# CSS for a pre-like element in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to define a CSS class that will provide the same style as HTML's `<pre>` element.
I tried this:

```
.mystyle { 
   display: block;
   font-family: monospace;
   white-space: pre;
}
```

which works fine on FF but not on IE (white-spaces are not kept). Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 7):

`white-space:pre` is supported only by IE6 and newer.

Your page probably doesn't have `DOCTYPE` or has and outdated one, which enables emulation of IE**5** in all newer versions of IE.

Add HTML4 Strict `DOCTYPE` to your document. Make sure there isn't anything else before `DOCTYPE`, because IE6 won't "see" it.